# printf is "eating" the backslashes. How to preserve them?

Tags: bash, shell, printf, sh, posix

I'm trying to make a tiny POSIX-compatible sed-like function. However I noticed that the code below is "eating" the backslashes.

`input.txt` for `mysed ./input.txt "TEST2" "TEST2=\"two\""` call :

```
TEST1="\\_PR.CP%02d"
TEST2="one"
TEST3="\\_PR.P%03d"
```

Expected:

```
TEST1="\\_PR.CP%02d"
TEST2="two"
TEST3="\\_PR.P%03d"
```

Received:

```
TEST1="\_PR.CP%02d"
TEST2="two"
TEST3="\_PR.P%03d"
```

How to modify the code below to preserve all the backslashes? Maybe it's possible to replace a custom `printf '%b\n'` format by something better?

```
#!/bin/sh
# Replaces the lines containing the text '$2' of a file '$1' with a line '$3'.
mysed () {
    if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
        mysed_tmp="./.mysed"
        rm -f $mysed_tmp
        while IFS= read -r line
        do
            case $line in
                *"$2"*)
                    if [ ! -z "$3" ] ; then
                        printf '%b\n' "$3" >> $mysed_tmp
                    fi
                    ;;
                *)
                    printf '%b\n' "$line" >> $mysed_tmp
                    ;;
            esac
        done < "$1"
        mv $mysed_tmp $1
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

echo "TEST1=\"\\\\_PR.CP%02d\"" > input.txt
echo "TEST2=\"one\"" >> input.txt
echo "TEST3=\"\\\\_PR.P%03d\"" >> input.txt

mysed ./input.txt "TEST2" "TEST2=\"two\""
cat ./input.txt
```

**EDIT:** replaced `'%b\n'` with `'%s\n'`, everything is working now as intended.

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double. Always enclose strings and scripts in single quotes until if/when you **need** double quotes and then use those until if/when you **need** no quotes. Double are for when you need the shell to interpret the contents so you appear to be asking the shell to strip backslashes and then surprised when the shell strips backslashes. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. If that's not all you need then come up with and post a minimal script that demonstrates the specific problem you're asking about.

Comment: @EdMorton When I replace the double quotes with single, it doesn't interpret the variables - resulting in this output:
    `$line`
    `$3`
    `$line`

Comment: I added an answer showing what I'm talking about. If that's not clear or doesn't answer your question then please come up with and post a [mcve] demonstrating just the specific problem you're asking about to get more help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look:

```
$ x="TEST2=\"two\""; printf '%s\n' "$x"
TEST2="two"

$ x='TEST2=\"two\"'; printf '%s\n' "$x"
TEST2=\"two\"

$ TEST1="\\_PR.CP%02d"; printf '%s\n' "$TEST1"
\_PR.CP%02d

$ TEST1='\\_PR.CP%02d'; printf '%s\n' "$TEST1"
\\_PR.CP%02d
```

Hopefully this will make things clearer:

```
$ foo() { printf '%%b:<%b>\n%%s:<%s>\n---\n' "$1" "$1"; }

$ foo "TEST2=\\"two\\""
%b:<TEST2=      wo\>
%s:<TEST2=\two\>
---

$ foo 'TEST2=\\"two\\"'
%b:<TEST2=\"two\">
%s:<TEST2=\\"two\\">
---
```

So:

1. If you don't want backslashes stripped by the shell when the string is defined then don't tell the shell to interpret them - use `'` not `"`.
2. If you don't want backslashes stripped by printf when the string is printed then don't tell printf to interpret them - use `%s` not `%b`.

Comment: Thank you very much! After I replaced `'%b\n'` with `'%s\n'` following your example, everything is working now as intended.

Comment: That's not what I'm demonstrating in my answer, I'm showing that you need to use single quotes when defining the variables - you can see in my answer that using double quotes instead of single is what causes the shell to strip one of the backslashes. Using %b when printing the variables is just yet another layer of peeling backslashes.

Comment: I added a function to the end of my answer that will hopefully clarify things.

Comment: Thank you very much for you kind explanation, really useful! Wish you a great day!